# JEXL program have ";" exception

Tags: java

I am doing rnd for JEXL but i got exception for the below program;

```
        String strDuration = "4560";
        long lDuration = Long.parseLong(strDuration);
        String theExpression = "" +
                "if(lDuration > 500)" +
                "   return true;" +
                "else" +
                "   return false;";

        Expression e =  jexl.createExpression( theExpression );
        JexlContext context = new MapContext();
        context.set("lDuration", lDuration);
        Boolean result =(Boolean) e.evaluate(context);
        System.out.println("The answer : " + result);
```

Exception  :
Caused by: org.apache.commons.jexl2.parser.ParseException: Ambiguous statement @1:30, missing ';' between expressions

Can anyone help me to display the output that i want(the boolean)?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here you go:

```
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    String strDuration = "4560";
    long lDuration = Long.parseLong(strDuration);
    String theExpression = "(lDuration > 500) ? true : false;";
    JexlEngine jexl = new JexlEngine();
    Expression e = jexl.createExpression(theExpression);
    JexlContext context = new MapContext();
    context.set("lDuration", lDuration);
    Boolean result = (Boolean) e.evaluate(context);
    System.out.println("The answer : " + result);
  }
```

Edit:
To be clear the problem is your use of the return statement, it appears to not be supported by JEXL.